# How to resize and convert mov to mp4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, mp4, video-conversion, mov

I have a very heavy mov video that I need to convert to mp4 and resize.

I tried some applications like Mencoder and Ffmpeg but none worked.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg is the best solution for you, try the next commands again:

Install the tool with the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Convert the video the the next command:

```
ffmpeg -i VideoName.mov -map 0 -c copy VideoName.mp4
```

Reduce the size with the next command:

```
ffmpeg -i VideoName.mp4 -r 30 -s 960x540 NewVideoName.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Handbrake ;)
It's a free program and is really easy to use. Specially if you don't want to use the terminal.